# How do register allocators actually work?

Tags: compilation, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization, cpu-registers

If you pick up a copy of almost any compiler construction textbook, it will tell you that the problem of register allocation boils down to coloring the interference graph. But talk to an LLVM developer, [and they'll tell you](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2011-11/Olesen_RegisterAllocation.pdf):

> - Interference graph is expensive to build
> - Spill code placement is more important than coloring
> - Need to model aliases and overlapping register classes
> - Flexibility is more important than the coloring algorithm

So what algorithms are actually used? What are the extra concerns that these algorithms are designed to handle?

Comment: There is Linear Scan Register Allocation: http://web.cs.ucla.edu/~palsberg/course/cs132/linearscan.pdf